# Not able to change the width of a table column in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have a jsp page with a table and i need it to have fixed sized columns . to achieve this i am using

```html
    table {
        table-layout: fixed;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

The problem is that it fixes the entire table and i am not able to shorten the width of the first despite trying various methods . How can this be achieved . Here's my Jsp page for the reference

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec"
 uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Categories</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/static/css/header.css" />'>
<script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

th {
text-align:center;
}
#categorySelect {
 text-align: center;
}

#categorySelect {
 margin: auto;
 width: 30%;
}

#123 {
 margin: auto;
 width: 50%;
}
p {
 font:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <jsp:include page="../shared/header.jsp">
  <jsp:param value="editCategories" name="currentPage" />
 </jsp:include>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="text-center">
   <h2>Select Category</h2>
   <div class="text-muted">
    <h4>Choose a Category to Edit, Update and Schedule Changes</h4>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group" id="categorySelect">
  <label for="categoryMenu">Select Category</label> <select
   class="form-control" id="categoryMenu">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
   <c:forEach items="${category}" var="catitem">
     <option>${catitem}</option>
   </c:forEach>
  </select>
 </div>
 <br></br>

 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="updateCategory" method=POST>
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
        <tr>
        <th>Property</th>
        <th>Present Value</th>
        <th>Edited Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="width:10%" align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
         <td class="col-sm-3"><p class="text-danger" id="id1">Id</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" placeholder="Enter Id"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td style="width:10%" align="center"><strong>Cat Key</strong></td>
<!--         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="catKey1" name="catKey1" placeholder="Enter CatKey"></td> -->
       <td class="col-sm-3"><p class="text-danger" id="catKey1">Cat Key</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="catKey" name="catKey" placeholder="Enter CatKey"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td style="width:10%" align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-3"><p class="text-danger" id="name1">Name</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td style="width:10%" align="center"><strong>Icon</strong></td>
         <td class="col-sm-3"><p class="text-danger" id="icon1">Icon</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="icon" name="icon" placeholder="Enter Icon"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td style="width:10%" align="center"><strong>Icon White</strong></td>
        <td class="col-sm-3"><p class="text-danger" id="iconWhite1">Icon White</p></td>
         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="iconWhite" name="iconWhite" placeholder="Enter IconWhite"></td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="width:10%" align="center"><strong>Color</strong></td>
         <td class="col-sm-3"><p class="text-danger" id="color1">Color</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="color" name="color" placeholder="Enter Color"></td>
  </tr>
       <tr>
     

     <td colspan="3" align="center">
  <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </td>

    </tr>
</table>
</div>
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
   $("#categoryMenu").change(function() {
    var category = $("#categoryMenu").val();
    loadData(category);

   });
 
  });
  
  function loadData(category) {
   $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    data : {
     categor : category
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    url : "printCategoryDetails",
    success : function(data) {
     $("#id1").html("<strong>"+ data.id + "</strong>");
      $("#id").val(data.id); 
     $("#id1").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#id").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#catKey").val(data.catkey); 
     $("#catKey1").html("<strong>"+ data.catkey + "</strong>");
     $("#catKey1").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#catKey").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#name").val(data.name);
     $("#name1").html("<strong>"+ data.name + "</strong>");
     $("#name1").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#icon").val(data.icon);
     $("#icon1").html("<strong>"+ data.icon + "</strong>");
     $("#icon1").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#iconWhite1").html("<strong>"+ data.icon_white + "</strong>");
     $("#iconWhite").val(data.icon_white);
     $("#iconWhite1").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#color1").html("<strong>"+ data.color+ "</strong>");
     $("#color1").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#color").val(data.color);
    
    },
    error : function() {
     alert("error");
    }

   });

  }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `table-layout:fixed` browsers aren't waiting for all rows - tables are drawn once you get first row. If you need to specify columns width, you have to do it on first row.

Your first row is a header, so setting

```
<th style="width:10%">
```

should do the work. You don't have to set it on any row afterwards, so you can just drop the style from tds.